# Colorpicker Spectrum doesn't show on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, spectrumjs

I'm using colorpicker Spectrum and what I'm trying to do is to open the colorpicker window when the input is focused. But the problem is that the colorpicker only shows for a split second and then closes. [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ssnmygj/1/)

HTML:

```
<input type="text">
```

Javascript:

```
$('input').spectrum().show();
$('input').focus(function() {
  $(this).spectrum('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
  $('input').spectrum().show();
  $("input").bind('focus click', function() { 
      $(this).spectrum("show");
      return false;
   });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/siinsn/0yn3bwgr/)